# Only one grandchild killed instead of 5

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, embedded

This is written from scratch version of my previous question. What I really need to achieve is: in future *parent* work to be able to close one end of *pipe* so  *grandchild* ( daemon ) would receive **SIGPIPE**. When I  use 1 solution it works like a charm ( but this is before any forking ). When I use 2 solution only one write generates SIGPIPE. How do I check this? By issuing: strace -f ./a.out 2>&1 | grep PIPE

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void child_become_daemon( int pfd[][2], int id )
{
    int pid = fork();
    if( pid == 0 )
    {
        dup2( pfd[id][1], 1 );
        close( pfd[id][0] );
        sleep( 5 ); //this is to be sure that opposite end is already closed
        write( 1, "child", strlen( "child" ) );
    }
    if( pid > 0 )
    {
        exit( 0 );
    }
}

int main()
{
    int pid;
    int numKids = 5;
    int procNum;

    int pfd[numKids][2];
    for( int i = 0; i < numKids; ++i )
    {
        pipe( pfd[ i ] );
        //close( pfd[i][0] );//1 all killed - perfect
    }

    for( procNum = 0; procNum < numKids; procNum++ ) {
        pid = fork();
        if( pid == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if( pid == 0 ) {
        printf( "I'm child %d\n", procNum );
        child_become_daemon( pfd, procNum );
    }
    else {
        for( int i = 0; i < numKids; ++i )
        {
            printf( "closing %d\n", i );
            close( pfd[i][0] );//2 why only one will get killed
            close( pfd[i][1] );
        }

        char buf[124] = { 0 };
        for( int i = 0; i < numKids; ++i )
        {
            read( pfd[i][0], buf, 124 );
            printf( "buf: %s\n", buf );
        }

         int p, status;
         while ((p = wait(&status)) != -1)
             fprintf(stderr, "p %d exits with %d\n", p, WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The grandchildren inherit all 5 pipes, so they each have the other 4 pipes open for read, hence no SIGPIPE.  If there is an "unlucky" timing the last one alive might get a SIGPIPE because the rest are gone.

[EDIT]
Also you have no way to know really, because you can't wait for grandchild processes if their parent is dead.  And you don't catch SIGPIPE in the grandkids.